# An admissible epi which is moreover monic is an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{E})$ be an exact category, in which we have an admissible epimorphism which is moreover monic in the categorical sense. Must this be an isomorphism?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. If $f \colon A \to B$ is your map, then just apply the Five Lemma for exact categories to the natural map from the kernel-cokernel pair $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B$ to the kernel-cokernel pair $0 \to B \to B$.